# Why does @RequestParameter String someValue in Spring 3 return 2x values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have this method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void captcha(@RequestParam String someValue, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    System.out.println(someValue);
}
```

Why does the result of this request:

```
http://something/home?someValue=testvalue123
```

return this?

```
testvalue123,testvalue123
```

Using an Int only gives a single value as expected, but not String. Getting the parameter directly from the request-object also gives a single value.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do? There's no parameter in the request called `someValue`, so your example doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a filter applied from some other library that incorrectly added the same request parameter a second time!

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you tell what filter was that?

Comment: @user405935 sure, I believe it was the this UrlrewriteFilter: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: we've since moved on to Spring :)

Answer (score 0):

does adding "test" value to the @RequestParam Annotation help:

```
@RequestParam("test") String someValue
```

Comment: No, still returnes the value twice.